# How to get the maximum id of DOM element with unordered pattern

Tags: jquery, attributes, traversal

I have an unordered list of form elements with ids

```
 <ul class="sortable" id="userForm">
<li style="visibility: hidden;" class="ui-state-default">Test</li>
<li style="display: list-item;" class="ui-state-default">
<div class="control">
  <label class="">Label Here</label>
  <textarea readonly="readonly" id="4"></textarea>
  <div class="delete" style="display: inline;"><sup>x</sup></div>
  <div class="properties txtarea" style="display: inline;">Properties</div>
</div>
</li>
<li style="display: list-item;" class="ui-state-default ">
<div class="control">
  <label class="">Label Here</label>
  <input readonly="readonly" id="3" name="txt" value="" type="text">
  <div class="delete" style="display: inline;"><sup>x</sup></div>
  <div class="properties txtbox" style="display: inline;">Properties</div>
</div>
  </li>
  <li style="display: list-item;" class="ui-state-default">
<div class="control">
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <input id="2" type="radio">
  <span class="controlText">Radio Button</span>
  <div class="delete" style="display: inline;"><sup>x</sup></div>
  <div class="properties radio" style="display: inline;">Properties</div>
</div>
 </li>
<li style="display: list-item;" class="ui-state-default">
<div class="control">
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <input id="1" type="checkbox">
  <span class="controlText">Check Box</span>
  <div class="delete" style="display: inline;"><sup>x</sup></div>
  <div class="properties chkbox" style="display: inline;">Properties</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

How can i get the Maximum id from these elements. The Ids are not in a particular order but the element classes and format is same.

Comment: Wait, what is it you're exactly trying to do here?

Comment: What do you mean "maximum id"? Do you want the total number of id? or the id with the biggest value? If the second keep in mind that you can't start an id with number http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name

Comment: well i need the id with the biggest value.. and the issue that id can not be a number I Know that but here these are not the real ids.. you have not seen the BIG picture...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this could work

```
var max = 0;
$('.control').each(function(i,n){
 // var check = $(n).children('input').attr('id')/*.prop() if jquery 1.6*/
  var check = $(n).children('.the_id').attr('id')/*.prop() if jquery 1.6*/
  if(check>max) max = check;
});
```

Here is a [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/BR6U3/) version

Comment: If you can see the second child is not always the INPUT but it can be a textarea a select option etc.... so i think this will not work

Comment: use a class instead of the tag name... so input `<input class="the_id" id="4" />` textarea `<textarea class="the_id" id="5"></textarea>`

Comment: That will make me to Make the Whole Module from Start. Is there NO WAY i can get the max id value from the controls div?

Comment: use `.children('[id]')` that means you can get the elements that only have the ID as an attribute, no changes to your html

Comment: FYI:  you can also use `.children(':input')` this selects all the inputs textarea, input, select etc...

Answer (score 4):

try the following code:

```
var maxId = 0;
$(".sortable *[id]").each(function() {
    if(maxId < $(this).attr("id")){ maxId = $(this).attr("id")}
});

alert("max id value is: "+maxId);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5UZTD/

Answer (score 0):

building on Val's answer

```
var max = 0;
$('.control *[id]').each(function(i,n){
  var check = $(n).attr('id')/*.prop() if jquery 1.6*/
  if(check>max) max = check;
});
```

the selector finds any element with an id [attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).